# Java: Renaming a file downloaded from remote server

Tags: java, string

In my app,I am downloading file from remote server. I am saving file with its original name. The problem is, in the url name appears,as follows:
**03%20Nas%20murrgo%20shov.mp3** while the actual file name is **Nas murrgo shov.mp3**. So, how can I format the file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your string is URL encoded. Try :

```
java.net.URLDecoder.decode(filename, "UTF-8");
```